# what does (function () { ... })(); mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see that in many modules for node.js and also for browser, they use to have all their code inside something like this:

```
(function () {

  moduleName.prototype.variable = 'whatever';

})();
```

Can anyone please explain what this all is, or any links that explain? I have no idea how to search it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pattern called [*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern called [*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

It's mostly useful for isolation purposes.